# twitter request limit

Tags: python, twitter

Regarding the twitter API request limit, how does one counts as a request?

I'm using python-twitter, so if I have

```
 client = twitter.Api(username='acc',password='pw')
 self.client.GetFriends(result[0])
```

Does this count as 1 request? Or as many as the number of friends I have? I asked this because I have the following code:

```
for user in friends:
        name = user.GetScreenName()
        print 'username is ' + name
        try:             
           messages = self.client.GetUserTimeline(user= name,count = 15)
           for message in messages:
              print 'message: ' + message.getText()
```

And I already got a bad request error code without even displaying a single status message.

Comment: I don't use Twitter API, but "request" is how many "questions" your sending to API, not how many responses you are receiving. So If there are no extra information this must be counted as "1 request".

Comment: What is the error code and message?

Comment: @Peter, the first error after printing the username is 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object', and the subsequent ones are 'HTTP Error 400: Bad Request' no status messages are printed.

Comment: could it be that the users' tweets are private and I do not have access to it?

Comment: that error is not related with twitter api, it's related with your (or the library) Python code.
What you mention about the 400 error is possible about the private tweets issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's 1 request. For that request Twitter will return a json file representing the list of friends.

Also the twitter.API call also produce a request, but this one is not counted for the limit stuff.

You can read about it in [apiwiki](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Rate-limiting)

You can also request your [limit status](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-account%C2%A0rate_limit_status).

Comment: you are correct. The reason is due to the private tweets. But what I am baffled is that why python-twitter do not product an exception for accessing unauthorised tweets.